# Azure Mobile Service is slow in the United States

Tags: web-services, azure, mobile, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

My app uses the South East Asian Microsoft Azure server and I think that might be the problem why people in the United States face issues regarding the app's efficiency. How do I get around this in Microsoft Azure? Do I need to purchase mirror servers, etc? I am very illiterate when it comes to server/hardware related stuff.

- The SQL Database is also hosted in the South East Asian region
- The Mobile backend is in the same region
- The Blob Storage is in the same region

Could this be the reason why people in the other end of the world face 'slowing' issues?

Can someone point out how I can make sure that my app service is available worldwide instead of limiting it to a specific region?

Comment: There's no right answer to this. And while regional distance is likely related to your performance issues, you should do some performance measurement around latency before you jump to that conclusion. As it stands now, there's really no way to answer this question, since root cause of the issue isn't known.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Considering how Azure's business model works, is it necessary for developers to purchase servers from multiple locations to enable worldwide coverage or does the basic tier (which I have purchased) already cover worldwide availability?

Comment: There's no single answer to that question (plus... you shouldn't be thinking in terms of *servers* - you don't ever buy a server with Azure). You need to think about how your app is accessed. You're free to use resources in any regions you choose.